# Flutter: how to configure the pubspec.yaml to change the app icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the default icon to my flutter app when I launch it in the iOS simulator.

I edited the pubspec.yaml file, adding the "flutter_launcher_icons:" under dev_dependencites and than another "flutter_launcher_icons:" block few lines below. Nothing happens.
The odd thing is that if I indent it in a different way I even get errors... Can a configuration file really rely on tabs??

Thank you for any advice...

```
name: flutter_application_1
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "images/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/

  fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: font/Montserrat-Regular.ttf
        - asset: font/Montserrat-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Comment: Have you executed this command flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add version to `flutter_launcher_icons` please replace your code with this to add version:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But in the output console I read: flutter_launcher_icons 0.9.2 (was 0.13.1) (0.13.1 available)
So it seems it was using version 0.13.1 before (the latest). Why 0.9.2 is the correct one?

Comment: You can update it I just copied this code from my project and I didn't update it yet. I will also update the version on my project.